# Unable to connect mac from remote using telnet

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, proxy, network

I am trying to use my mac as proxy using charles proxy. To do that, I had my mac and android device in same network and manually set the mac ip as proxy in the android device settings at port 8888.

Now I am unable to connect to internet through the android device. Upon pondering i noticed that my mac was refusing connections from any remote device through telnet, while it was connecting if I try to connect from the same machine (i.e telnet localhost 8888).

Also my mac can be connected using ssh from other device in same network and the firewall is disabled. What can be that is preventing the machine to not accept inbound connections from remote machines?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I was using an unstable version of Symantec antivirus which blocked many incoming connections as well as the airdrop feature in mac. I downgraded it, which solved the problem.